# Microsoft Test Manager (MTM) with Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-test-manager

I'm having problems connecting Microsoft Test Manager to a Visual Studio Online account.

I've tried connecting from different computers, with different versions of Microsoft Test Manager (2012 & 2013)

I get the error `TF30063: You are not authorized to access myVSO.visualstudio.com`.

**I have a Licenced Visual Studio Premium with MSDN configured, not a FREE Visual Studio Online Basic Account**

Is Microsoft Test Manager supported with Visual Studio Online? If it is, suggestions? I'm logging with the same account that created the Visual Studio Online account and I have full permissions on everything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you connect to the web access do you get a Test tab?

If you do not then you are not licenced for Test Management. You can try going to your  [account homepage](http://myvso.visualstudio.com) and select "try full features" or click "Users" and move yourself from "free" to "MSDN".

Free users do not get access to the features that you are trying to use:
[image]

Comment: I am a MSDN Subscriber with Visual Studio Premium and my user is already configured in the VSO account

Comment: Do you see the Test tab in Web Access?

Comment: if by test lab you mean the test Tab, then yes.

Comment: If you have the Test tab then you should be able to connect MTM to your Team Project. What happens when you go to "https://myvso.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Components/_testManagement"

Comment: It displays a web interface similar to MTM. I missread when you said test tab, I understood test "lab". Yes I see the Test Tab and it works perfectly.

Comment: Then you likely have git a bug and should raise it with MSFT through http://visualstudio.com...

Comment: Which Visual Studio Update do you have installed?  Do you have Update 4 installed?  http://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2013-update4-rtm-vs

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work, but had to jump through a few hoops.  Some ideas of things to try:

1. Using the Visual Studio IDE (I'm using 2013 Ultimate), open the Team Explorer tool window and try to add your *.visualstudio.com server to the list of TFS servers. If you can connect successfully in Visual Studio, MTM should pick up the same list of servers and will automatically log you in.
2. If that doesn't work, you can try adding the following registry key, and then launching MTM again:
   **reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\TeamFoundation /v LegacyMSA /d True /f**